# Quickest way to write a little server

Tags: java, android, iphone, networking

I need a remote computer to communicate with my android/iPhone apps to do things like promote, get stats... What's the fastest way to achieve this? No html needed, it's just for short (most likely JSON) messages between me and myself.

I have an account on my university's CS unix-based server on which I can host content. Tutorials greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Check parse.com or stackmob.com

Comment: Rog was right. Parse.com is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

Now sure why you want to reinvent the wheel. Writing a web server would involve low level socket communication, putting up a protocol and bunch of code to handle these things. Please check [Tiny Java web server](http://tjws.sourceforge.net/), or [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) .

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a Web Application (maybe in PHP or Java), and then you'll have to host this application on a web server.